# Ratio of the heights of triangle is given, determine the sides of triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, ratio

Can someone help me with this excersize?
The ratio of heights to the sides of the triangle is v_{a}:v_{b}:v_{c}=12:5:8. What are the length of the sides of triangle? (a,b,c=?) 
Thank you!

I tried using formula for area of triangle, e.g. P=(a*v_a)/2 and P=(b*v_b)/2 and then I would get b=12/5 a and I did that for other combinations but did not come up with anything.

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: I tried using formula for area of triangle, e.g. P=(a*v_a)/2 and P=(b*v_b)/2 and then I would get b=12/5 a and I did that for other combinations but did not come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea works!

Since $$S=\frac{ah_a}{2}=\frac{bh_b}{2}=\frac{ch_c}{2},$$ we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{a}:\frac{1}{b}:\frac{1}{c}=12:5:8$$ or
$$a:b:c=\frac{1}{12}:\frac{1}{5}:\frac{1}{8}.$$
We need to check that $$\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{8}>\frac{1}{5},$$ of course.

For minimal natural's $a$, $b$ and $c$ we obtain $(10,24,15).$

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your hint, it is already given that h_{a}:h_{b}:h_{c}=12:5:8.

Comment: @Lori_P I added something. See now.

Comment: Yes, I saw, but since it is given h_{a}:h_{b}:h_{c}=12:5:8, it can't be at the sime time h_{a}:h_{b}:h_{c}=1/12:1/5:1/8.

Comment: @Lori_P I did not understand the problem true. I fixed. See now.

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Lori_P You are welcome!